# PHP - simple refactor

Tags: php, refactoring

I have the following code:

```
$image_1 = $value->getElementsByTagName("Image1");
$image1  = $image_1->item(0)->nodeValue;

$image_2 = $value->getElementsByTagName("Image2");
$image2  = $image_2->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

Is there an easier way, to not repeat code If I need $image_3 ?

i.e. how can I refactor this?

Thanks

UPDATE:

I am using the $images_x variables in further code, that also needs refactoring:

UPDATE 2: - My full code:

```
$image_1 = $value->getElementsByTagName("Image1");
$image1  = $image_1->item(0)->nodeValue;

$image_2 = $value->getElementsByTagName("Image2");
$image2  = $image_2->item(0)->nodeValue;

$image_3 = $value->getElementsByTagName("Image3");
$image3  = $image_3->item(0)->nodeValue;

$filename_1 = basename($image1);
$ch = curl_init ($image1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER,1);
$rawdata_1=curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
$fp = fopen(Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'import/'.$filename_1,'w');
fwrite($fp, $rawdata_1);
fclose($fp);

$filename_2 = basename($image2);
$ch = curl_init ($image2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER,1);
$rawdata_2=curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
$fp = fopen(Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'import/'.$filename_2,'w');
fwrite($fp, $rawdata_2);
fclose($fp);

$filename_3 = basename($image3);
$ch = curl_init ($image3);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER,1);
$rawdata_3=curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
$fp = fopen(Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'import/'.$filename_3,'w');
fwrite($fp, $rawdata_3);
fclose($fp);

$product->addImageToMediaGallery(Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'import/' .  $filename_1, array('image', 'small_image','thumbnail'), false, false);
$product->addImageToMediaGallery(Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'import/' .  $filename_2, array('image', 'small_image','thumbnail'), false, false);
$product->addImageToMediaGallery(Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'import/' .  $filename_3, array('image', 'small_image','thumbnail'), false, false);
```

Comment: Next time, I would just post your full question the first time around. But really, why not make the curl fetch in a function and then use meze's answer and call that function inside the loop?

Comment: this also seems like a good candidate for codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use loops:

```
$images = array();
for ($i = 1; $i <= 2; $i++) {
   $images[] = $value->getElementsByTagName("Image" . $i)->item(0)->nodeValue;
}

// and then you can get an image via $images[0], $images[1] and so on
```

All code can be rewritten as Brad F Jacobs suggested:

```
function downloadAndSave($image) {
    $filename = basename($image);
    $ch = curl_init ($image);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER,1);
    $rawdata=curl_exec ($ch);
    curl_close ($ch);
    $fp = fopen(Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'import/'.$filename,'w');
    fwrite($fp, $rawdata);
    fclose($fp);
    return $filename;
}
// here you should have another loop, suppose foreach ($products as $product) {
    for ($i = 1; $i <= 2; $i++) {
       $filename = downloadAndSave($value->getElementsByTagName("Image" . $i)->item(0)->nodeValue);
       $product->addImageToMediaGallery(Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'import/' .  $filename, array('image', 'small_image','thumbnail'), false, false);
    }
// end of foreach }
```

Comment: Either there are only so many ways to do it, or we're psychically linked. ;)

Comment: That works great, but i also have further code that is dependent on the $images_x variable, I will update my code:

Comment: Pretty much what I had for my answer :)

Comment: @meze thanks for that. That kind of works. My script is looping throguh an XML file, to insert records to a DB. But the code you provided, only seems to find the images for the first product in the XML file

Comment: @terrid25 did your code find images for all products? i just noticed did you have `$fp` for the `$filename_2`?

Comment: @meze yes it did. There's about 40 in the XML file. But adding your code, only added 1

Comment: @terrid25 do the images have the same names in your XML? It would be nice if you could update your question and add missing code for $filename_2

Comment: @meze The anmes in the XML are all unique, but I think it may be some of my other code as well, as adding my code back, seems to insert more images than it should

Comment: @terrid25 Well without looking at your all your code we can't say what is wrong. Make sure that you don't use `$i` in another place, and that `for` is inside your loop if you have one. Also you can debug it by adding this inside for-loop: `echo "Saving image " . ($value->getElementsByTagName("Image" . $i)->item(0)->nodeValue) . "<br>\r\n";`

Comment: @terrid25 updated the answer too. if it doesn't work, make sure downloadAndSave is called for each product

Answer (score 1):

```
$images = array();
for ($x = 1; $x <= 3; $x++) {
    $images[] = $value->getElementsByTagName("Image$x")->item(0)->nodeValue;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could bundle this into a function:

```
$image = getImage("Image1");

function getImage($path)
{
  $image_raw = $value->getElementsByTagName($path);
  return $image_raw->item(0)->nodeValue;
}
```

Furthermore, you could read the resource names from a file (if this is appropriate in the context you wish to use this in), returning an array of values in a foreach loop:

Pseudocode:

```
$imgArray = array();

foreach($pathNames as $path)
{
   $imgArray[] = getImage($path);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a loop?

```
$max_ids = 5; // or whatever
$images = array();

for( $i=1; $i <= $max_ids; $i++ ) {
    $images[$i]['tag'] = $value->getElementsByTagName("Image$i");
    $images[$i]['value'] = $image[$i]['tag']->item(0)->nodeValue;
}
```

Also creates a data structure for your images.

Answer (score 1):

Best use arrays. This will give you an array of images:

```
for ($i = 1; $i < 3; $i++)
{
  $imageElement = $value->getElementsByTagName("Image".$i);
  $imageElements[] = $imageElement;
  $images[] = $imageElement->item(0)->nodeValue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

create a function to combine the two lines.